# Deciding Which of Two Functions Increases Faster..

Tags: calculus, limits

Say I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I am asked to prove that $g(x)$ grows faster than $f(x)$. The common way is taking the ratio $f(x)/g(x)$ and making $x$ go to infinity, that way the ratio goes to 0. I think there are other ways however; Why not take the difference $g(x)-f(x)$, if $x$ goes to infinity then $g(x)-f(x)$ goes to infinity as well. Alternatively, the derivatives of the two functions can be compared... If $g'(x) > f'(x)$ then surely $g(x)$ grows faster than $f(x)$. Are the two latter methods correct? If so, why are they not so commonly used.

Comment: because people don't need to prove non-rigorous/vague statements such as "$g$ grows faster than $f$"; they need to prove certain, precise statements. Usually what one needs to prove for whatever application is $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For example if $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x$ then we have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=\infty$$
but clearly $f(x)$ does not increase infinitely faster than $g(x)$. Your second statement is more correct because if two functions tend to infinity then we can apply L'Hopitals rule and instead compare the ratio of $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$. But this only works if the ratio of $f'(x)$ to $g'(x)$ converges to a finite limit.

Answer (score 0):

These are definitions. You cannot ask if a definition is correct. They are all reasonable definitions of $g$ growing faster than $f$ but they are not equivalent. So we choose the definition that is most useful to us.  It turns out that the most useful one is the first one so that is the one most people use.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid too many additional complications, let's assume that for $x \gt 0$ you have $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both being positive and differentiable and strictly increasing.  Let's look for examples to expose some of the differences between various tests of *growing faster*

There seem to be many possible tests, including:

1. $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =0$;
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 1$;
3. $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \bigl(g(x) - f(x)\bigr) =\infty$;
4. $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} < 1$;
5. $g'(x) \gt f'(x) \, \forall x \gt 0$

Now consider some examples

- $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^x$.  These pass all five tests
- $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2x$.  These pass tests 2, 3, 4 and 5 but not 1
- $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$.  These pass tests 1, 2, 3 and 4 but not 5
- $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^2+x$. These pass tests 2, 3 and 5, but not 1 or 4
- $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=2-2e^{-x}$. These pass tests 2, 4 and 5 but not 1 or 3
- $f(x)=4-e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=2-2e^{-x}$. These pass tests 4 and 5 but not 1, 2 or 3. In fact $f(x) > g(x) \forall x \gt 0$
- $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^x (2+\sin(x)-\cos(x))$.  These pass tests 1, 2 and 3 but not 4 or 5

and it would be possible to find more examples which pass some tests but not others (though some patterns are not possible: for example anything that passes test 1 will also pass test 2)

This could lead you to conclude that *growing faster* needs a more precise definition